# text/plain removed from list Content-Types default

Tags: mod-security

in the CRS v3.3.3 update, some Content-Types allowed in rule 900220 were removed and explanatory comment added, but it generated a doubt when I saw that text/plain was removed from this list.

Why not allow text/plain by default in Content-Types ? I ask because apparently many simple apps use text/plain CT.

n my understanding, plain text parsing would not need a specific content processor, unlike JSON and XML which have standard structures and demarcations. That's why I didn't understand the removal of the Content-Type "text/plain"

Following the idea that there is no body processor for Content-Type text/plain, so it looks like parsing is stuck exclusively on Content-Type, if in text/plain it is not possible to parse the body by default (core function) then would modsecurity be useful for parsing the body only for applications that work with JSON and XML?

I'm confused, but I hope you can clarify

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the change is described in the [issue #2768](https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset/pull/2768) which can be found by following git blame on the relevant line in the configuration.

> As we decided during the last meeting, this PR removes all previous allowed-by-default content-types that can't be parsed by any body-processor. The idea here is to warn the user about allowing content-type like "text/plain" and give a bit of advice on how to allow it on specific paths using a SecRule.